# lax or laxed vowels?

Tags: adjectives

> While both German and English have vowel reductions of some sort, English is much more **laxed** than German.

I found this sentence in a video, I don't see why there is a word "laxed" there. As I know, the word lax itself is an adjective. There shouldn't be a -ed added to the end of it. Is *laxed* even exist?

Answer (score 2):

It is used in phonetics with the same meaning:

[laxed](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/laxed):

> (phonetics) Of a vowel: made lax.

From [A Reference Grammar of Spoken Tamil](https://books.google.it/books?id=Oqe-QsaZnnQC&pg=PA14&dq=%22laxed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLg8r9uPbcAhVExhoKHWP2BDUQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22laxed%22&f=false)
By Harold F. Schiffman, Harold F. (university Of Pennsylvania)

> Medial Stop Consonants Single stop consonants (i.e. not double or geminated) in medial position (i.e. between two vowels) ***in Tamil are typically laxed and fricativized***. Thus the stop consonants u, (b, rb, l_, ff, a> in medial position are actually ...

From [Future challenges for natural linguistics](https://books.google.it/books?id=e2ZiAAAAMAAJ&q=%22laxed%22&dq=%22laxed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_h4r8ufbcAhWKz4UKHQS6DzE4ChDoAQhHMAg) by Jarosław Weckwerth
Lincom Europa, 2002 - Grammar, Comparative and general -

> Especially in English /i, e, u/, ***the first element may be laxed, and in /u, o/, the first element may be laxed or delabialized.*** American English /u/ is rarely a real |u|; it is more often [uy] or [iu|. and lol is usually [oy] or [ay]. We also have [ij] and [ei] for  ...

Comment: According to the web you provided, the word **laxed** is **not comparable**, but it was used as a comparable adjective in my example.

Comment: *Laxed* makes sense in the meaning 'made lax' (which is not the same as 'lax').  In the examples in this answer, *laxed* does mean 'made lax' and makes sense.  What do you suppose *laxed* means in the OP's example?

Comment: @snailboat - I think the meaning is fairly obvious. The OP should probably provide thier source.

Answer (score 0):

As user070221 points out, there is one, very specific case where "laxed" is appropriate: to describe the nature of a vowel sound in phonetics. This is an edge case, however.

The word "laxed" in your example, because it seems to deal with this specific case, is correct.

In all other circumstances, the word would be "lax."